# How to get funID?

Tags: solidity, everscale

need help to get the correct funcID. I've Tried many ways. Will be glad to get your help.
Thanks!

```
slugSha256() {
  slug=$(echo -n "$1" | sha256sum | cut -d' ' -f1)
  echo -n $((16#"${slug:0:8}"))
}
functionHash() {
  hash=$(slugSha256 "$(echo -n "$1" | sed 's/ //g')")
  if [[ "$1" == *constructor* ]]; then hash=$((hash ^ (2 ** 31))); fi
  printf '0x%x' "$hash"
}
functionID() { functionHash "$1v2"; }
```

`

```js
functionID "main()(string)" # 0xb0992770
functionID "redeem(uint256, string, uint256)()" # 0x58160fa0
functionID "constructor()()" # 0x68b55f3f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo.sol`

```
pragma ever-solidity >= 0.64.0;
contract foo {
 constructor() public {}
 function main() public returns (string) {}
 function redeem(uint256 a, string b, uint256 c) public {}
}
```

via [everdev](https://github.com/tonlabs/everdev) `npx everdev sol update`

`~/.everdev/solidity/solc --function-ids foo.sol`

via [sold](https://github.com/EverscaleGuild/ever-solidity/releases/tag/0.65.0):
`sold --function-ids foo.sol`

out:

```json
{
  "constructor": "0x68b55f3f",
  "main": "0x30992770",
  "redeem": "0x58160fa0"
}
```

via web tool https://ever.bytie.moe/serializer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the constructor, you need to clear the highest bit to get the correct funcID